# Sum specific row values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with many columns, i interested in column "a", column "b" and column "val". What i need is, to create query, when a is equal to specific int (lets say a=1) and b also equal to specific int (b=1). For every row that match that criteria i want to sum values, that indicated in "val" column. How to create that query?

Comment: A bit unclear, but sounds simple.  What did you try?

Comment: @sstan im an ios developer and not very familiar with SQL basics

Comment: Still, everyone is expected to do a little research/effort before posting a question. Maybe you did, but the question doesn't reflect that.

Comment: @sstan im sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a group by clause

```
select 
    a
    , b
    , sum(val)
from
    [YourTable]
group by
    a
    , b
having
    a = 1
    and b = 1
```

Comment: Having?  That evaluates the conditons after the query operates.  SELECT a, b, sum(val) from [table] where a=1 and b = 1 group by a, b;

Answer (score 2):

```
Select sum(val)
From table
Where a = @aVal 
    and b = @bVal
```

Answer (score 2):

select 
  sum(val) 
from 
your_table where a=1 and b=1

Comment: This will give you what you require. In case you need the value of a and b, just use group by function